# У меня есть код JS, который постоянно добавляет цифры, но проблема при обновлении

Tags: php, javascript

Всем добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код

```js
const interval = 444; // милисекунды
const min = 9;
const max = 46;
let number = 0;
setInterval(() => output.innerHTML = number += min + ~~(Math.random() * (max - min)), interval);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Он здорово работает, но я не могу никак сделать, что-бы при обновлении страницы не сбивались цифры с 0 (пробовал и выносить его отдельно), помогите пожалуйста есть ли решение?

И еще вопрос по теме, возможно ли как то заменить что бы  вместо `ID="output"` я вставил `ID="likes"` и код работал, это нужно что бы на одной странице несколько одинаковых кодов но с разными условиями работали?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Как бы Вы не пытались, перемение js постоянно будут обновляться при обновленные страницы. Вам нужно хранить счетчик или в cookies или local storage и когда идет загрузка страницы считывать исходное значение от них.